# Using default values in primary key

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, default-value

Good day.

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    myname varchar(30),
    mydate date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY(myname, mydate)
);
```

**EDIT**:
Forgot to mention I am using a view and a rule

So I have a view that is basically the same thing as the table

```
CREATE VIEW mytable_view (name, _date)
AS SELECT (myname, mydate)
FROM mytable;
```

And the rule is as follows:

```
CREATE RULE update_mytable
AS ON INSERT TO mytable_view
DO INSTEAD (
    INSERT INTO mytable(myname, mydate)
    VALUES(NEW.name, NEW._date);
);
```

Now I try to insert into the table using the view by doing this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable_view(name)
    VALUES("Mozzart");
```

However, I get an error saying:

> ERROR:  null value in column "mydate" violates not-null constraint

Why is this? I expected the default value to be used if the value being inserted is null or wasn't specified. Is this not how default works?

Comment: What DBMS is this?

Comment: @ypercube I am using dbvis

Comment: @ypercube I updated the question, I was actually inserting into a view not a table and I used a rule to control this

Comment: What's the point of the rule?

Comment: The rule is for the view. Can't insert into a view without the rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To begin with: for a simple view like that you don't need a rule (at least not in any current Postgres version).

---

The reason you get that problem is this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(myname, mydate)
VALUES(NEW.name, NEW._date);
```

Now if you don't supply value for `mydate` when inserting into the view, then `NEW._date` will be `null`, and thus you are trying to put an explicit `NULL` value into that column. You need to take that situation into account:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(myname, mydate)
VALUES(NEW.name, coalesce(NEW._date, current_date));
```

---

Unrelated but: you have another problem in your statement: `"Mozzart"` is a column name, string literals need to be enclosed in single quotes: `'Mozzart'`. Postgres should have thrown a `column "Mozzart" does not exist` error.

For details, please see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

---

Finally: your view definition is wrong:

```
SELECT (myname, mydate)
```

selects a ***single*** column that is an anonymous structure with two elements. You need to get rid of those useless parentheses, the `CREATE VIEW` should have thrown an error `CREATE VIEW specifies more column names than columns`.

You need to use:

```
CREATE VIEW mytable_view (name, _date)
AS 
SELECT myname, mydate --<< NO parentheses!
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get an answer to this earlier. What is the difference between `VALUES(NEW.name, coalesce(NEW._date, current_date));` and `VALUES(NEW.name, (SELECT coalesce(NEW._date, current_date)));`?

Comment: @Smac89: the first one is shorter and probably more efficient. Although syntactically correct, the second one just looks "wrong" in my eyes.